# How to display the current time continously in a different time zone?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I would like to display the current time continuously but in a different time zone?

The following code will display the current time continuously.

Can I update to get the time in a different time zone.?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowTime() {
        var dt = new Date();
        document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").value
        = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
        window.setTimeout("ShowTime()", 1000);
    }
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="time"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // a startup script to put everything in motion
    window.setTimeout("ShowTime()", 1000);
</script>
```

Please help
Thank you
Joe

Comment: Please don't pass strings to `setTimeout` and `setInterval`! Pass _functions_. Like this: `window.setTimeout(ShowTime, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

The [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library might be a good starting point. There's a `getTimezoneOffset` method that gives you the time offset for a given timezone.

Also, consider using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert date to timestamp and add the hours for the preffered timezone.

Convert tmestamp to date again.

var currentdate = 20101007163045

current timestamp= time(currentdate);

another timezone + 3 hours
var expectedtimestamp=timestamp + time(3hrs)

expecteddate= date(expectedtimestamp).

This is algorithm. check your syntaxes

Comment: Wont work, as the offset depends on the date and year, and sometimes country.